# Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?

Tags: c#, string

Are they really same? Today, I ran into this problem. Here is the dump from the Immediate Window:

```
?s 
"Category" 
?tvi.Header 
"Category" 
?s == tvi.Header 
false 
?s.Equals(tvi.Header) 
true 
?s == tvi.Header.ToString() 
true
```

So, both `s` and `tvi.Header` contain "Category", but `==` returns false and `Equals()` returns true.

`s` is defined as string, `tvi.Header` is actually a WPF `TreeViewItem.Header`. So, why are they returning different results? I always thought that they were interchangable in C#.

Can anybody explain why this is?

Comment: I think string.Equals matches the whole object

Comment: Yes, I get the same result from inside my code. Actually, it brought to my attention because == returns false in the code. I always use == for string comparison. This morning I couldn't believe == returns false when I see both sides contain the same string "Category" to my eye (I even asked my co-worker to double-check if I see something wrong). But it works fine when I changed it to use Equals (same result as shown in Immediate Window).

Comment: You should consider calling the `string.Equals` overloads that include a `StringComparison` parameter for most string comparisons. Use the InvarientCulture versions for coded strings (XML attributes for example) or CurrentCulture for user-entered strings. This will take care of a lot of details that == ignores, such as Unicode character normalization forms, etc., and it makes case sensitivity explicit.

Comment: @Robaticus, I don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: The .Equals method looks at the contents of the string, the == operator compares the objects. == will only return true if they actually are the same object. This can get tricky with internment, in that if you have string a = "test" and string b = "test" it will actually be the same object and return true in an == comparison.

Comment: == only works if the static type of the objects is string. Since operator overloading only takes the static type into consideration.

Answer (score 368):

Two differences:

- `Equals` is polymorphic (i.e. it can be overridden, and the implementation used will depend on the execution-time type of the target object), whereas the implementation of `==` used is determined based on the *compile-time* types of the objects:

  ```
    // Avoid getting confused by interning
    object x = new StringBuilder("hello").ToString();
    object y = new StringBuilder("hello").ToString();
    if (x.Equals(y)) // Yes

    // The compiler doesn't know to call ==(string, string) so it generates
    // a reference comparision instead
    if (x == y) // No

    string xs = (string) x;
    string ys = (string) y;

    // Now *this* will call ==(string, string), comparing values appropriately
    if (xs == ys) // Yes
  ```
- `Equals` will throw an exception if you call it on null, == won't

  ```
    string x = null;
    string y = null;

    if (x.Equals(y)) // NullReferenceException

    if (x == y) // Yes
  ```

Note that you can avoid the latter being a problem using `object.Equals`:

```
if (object.Equals(x, y)) // Fine even if x or y is null
```

Comment: Doesn't == also include a Object.ReferenceEquals check for a quick `true` if they are the same object?

Comment: @James: I'd expect that for both implementations, to be honest. But I haven't checked.

Comment: `x == y` equals false because you are checking reference equality with the object class' equality operator. `(string)x == (string)y` does in fact return true, in .Net 4.0 at least.

Comment: @Virtlink: Exactly; it's not polymorphic. I've edited the answer to make that more obvious.

Comment: It's true that the `==` operator is not polymorphic; however, if `==` calls any virtual methods within its implementation (and many do simply by delegating to the `Equals` method) then it could also exhibit polymorphic behavior.

Comment: @Michael And this is why there was no Y2K bug in **any** legacy code. ;^D  (aka, "I rolled scores on my 2600 games in base 10" aka ["Not everyone understands magic numbers"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak#Notable_magic_numbers))

Comment: Great answer. Wouldn't it make more sense to use `String.Equals(x, y)` instead of `object.Equals(x, y)` to avoid the null issue?

Comment: @Chaulky: How would that avoid the null issue any more than `object.Equals` does? The only benefit is that it restricts both values to be of type `string`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I was referring to that type check as being the advantage over `object.Equals(x, y)`. The question was about string comparisons, so it seems the added type check would be the benefit to using `String.Equals()` over `object.Equals()`. Is there a reason avoiding that type check would be better? Also, thanks for responding to a comment on question over a year old!

Comment: @Chaulky: No particular reason - other than I know `object.Equals` is *always* available to avoid nullity concerns, whereas for specific types I'd need to check the documentation :)

Answer (score 63):

The apparent contradictions that appear in the question are caused because in one case the `Equals` function is called on a `string` object, and in the other case the `==` operator is called on the `System.Object` type. `string` and `object` implement equality differently from each other (value vs. reference respectively).

Beyond this fact, any type can define `==` and `Equals` differently, so in general they are not interchangeable.

Here’s an example using `double` (from Joseph Albahari’s note to §7.9.2 of the C# language specification):

```
double x = double.NaN;
Console.WriteLine (x == x);         // False
Console.WriteLine (x != x);         // True
Console.WriteLine (x.Equals(x));    // True
```

He goes on to say that the `double.Equals(double)` method was designed to work correctly with lists and dictionaries. The `==` operator, on the other hand, was designed to follow the IEEE 754 standard for floating point types.

In the specific case of determining string equality, the industry preference is to use neither `==` nor `string.Equals(string)` most of the time. These methods determine whether two string are the same character-for-character, which is rarely the correct behavior. It is better to use `string.Equals(string, StringComparison)`, which allows you to specify a particular type of comparison. By using the correct comparison, you can avoid a lot of potential (very hard to diagnose) bugs.

Here’s one example:

```
string one = "Caf\u00e9";        // U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
string two = "Cafe\u0301";       // U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
Console.WriteLine(one == two);                                          // False
Console.WriteLine(one.Equals(two));                                     // False
Console.WriteLine(one.Equals(two, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));  // True
```

Both strings in this example look the same ("Café"), so this could be very tough to debug if using a naïve (ordinal) equality.

Answer (score 45):

C# has two "equals" concepts: `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals`.  For most classes you will encounter, the `==` operator uses one or the other (or both), and generally only tests for `ReferenceEquals` when handling reference types (but the `string` Class is an instance where C# already knows how to test for value equality).

- `Equals` compares values. (Even though two separate `int` variables don't exist in the same spot in memory, they can still contain the same value.)
- `ReferenceEquals` compares the reference and returns whether the operands point to the same object in memory.

Example Code:

```
var s1 = new StringBuilder("str");
var s2 = new StringBuilder("str");
StringBuilder sNull = null;

s1.Equals(s2); // True
object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2); // False
s1 == s2 // True - it calls Equals within operator overload
s1 == sNull // False
object.ReferenceEquals(s1, sNull); // False
s1.Equals(sNull); // Nono!  Explode (Exception)
```

Comment: This is not quite true... Try compare two actual string objects with `==` that are different reference but same value, you will get `true`. Jon Skeet explains this...

Comment: @Noldorin: This is why I said: "The `==` operator has to choose between them sometimes, and **generally** chooses `ReferenceEquals` when handling nullable types."  `string` is an example of a nullable type for which C# does not use only `ReferenceEquals`.  The OP asked about `string` objects, but really needs to understand general C# objects.

Comment: +1 Indeed, and [that is what makes comparison in C#/.NET so very confusing and seemingly unspecified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112625/vs-object-equalsobject-in-net/3576334#3576334).

Comment: It doesn't have to choose between them, it can do something different instead. Not often a good idea, but it can.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: Good point; you *can* overload the `==` operator to do anything you want.

Comment: @palswim you wrote in your comment "string is an example of a nullable type"but nullable types are a subcategory of value types. Strings are reference types. See Section 1.3 of the spec

Comment: The main problem with this answer is the idea that there is one `==` operator that behaves differently depending on its operands.  Because operators are *overloaded*, there are actually many `==` operators, and each one has whatever behavior its implementer has given it.  The compiler chooses a particular operator depending on the compile-time types of the two operands.  The rules governing that choice are described in section 7.3, Operators, of the C# spec version 5.0.

Comment: Another problem with this answer is that the example code does not compile -- for example, ReferenceEquals is not an instance method.  Fixing those problems, however, also shows that the last line (`s1.Equals(sNull);`) does not in fact throw an exception, but rather evaluates to false.  Why did you think it would throw an exception?

Comment: [Microsoft's Guidelines for Overriding the Equals and == Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx) can offer some elucidation and further explanation as well.

Answer (score 17):

The [`Header`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol.header.aspx) property of the `TreeViewItem` is statically typed to be of type `object`.

Therefore the `==` yields `false`. You can reproduce this with the following simple snippet:

```
object s1 = "Hallo";

// don't use a string literal to avoid interning
string s2 = new string(new char[] { 'H', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o' });

bool equals = s1 == s2;         // equals is false
equals = string.Equals(s1, s2); // equals is true
```

Comment: Is this a WPF thing? I just started with WPF. I never ran into this kind of problems before in WinForm apps. So, we should always use Equals instead of ==?

Comment: It's worth noting that `s1 == s2` becomes `s1.Equals(s2)` IFF both s1 and s2 are declared as strings.  String equality has special meaning in C#.

Comment: @miliu: As you can see from my sample this is not related to WPF but generally the case in .NET.

Comment: I believe it's actually spelled "H-e-l-l-o"

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/c-are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same/3678810#3678810), I'd like to explain why most of the time when using `==` you actually get the answer `true` on different string instances with the same value:

```
string a = "Hell";
string b = "Hello";
a = a + "o";
Console.WriteLine(a == b);
```

As you can see, `a` and `b` must be different string instances, but because strings are immutable, the runtime uses so called [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) to let both `a` and `b` reference the same string in memory. The `==` operator for objects checks reference, and since both `a` and `b` reference the same instance, the result is `true`. When you change either one of them, a new string instance is created, which is why string interning is possible.

By the way, Jon Skeet's answer is not complete. Indeed, `x == y` is `false` but that is only because he is comparing objects and objects compare by reference. If you'd write `(string)x == (string)y`, it will return `true` again. So strings have their ==-operator overloaded, which calls `String.Equals` underneath.

Comment: I had thought that was obvious enough from the answer, but I've edited it to be more complete. However, your answer about interning is *not* correct. `a` and `b` refer to *different* instances above; string interning is only applied to compile-time constants. Your code prints True because it calls the == overload called, which is comparing the character sequences. The string that `a` ends up referring to has *not* been interned.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Why does the string that `a` ends up referring to not interned? Is it because the compile-time value of `a` at the point of the comparison can not be determined? Would the initial `"Hell"` value be interned?

Comment: @Ax: Yes - it's not a compile-time constant. "Hell" would indeed be interned. (And "Hello" would exist in the intern pool of course due to `b`; but `a` would be the result of calling `String.Concat("Hell", "o");`

Comment: @Ax.: The system only interns non-constant strings when explicitly requested to do so, in part because once a string has been interned, the interned copy can never be garbage-collected.  If one happens to frequently use strings containing a particular sequence of 32,000 characters, interning the string may save 64K for each copy that would otherwise be created.  But if one interns a 32,000 character string and never again uses that sequence of characters, one will permanently waste 64K of memory.  Programs can't afford to do that too many times.

Comment: @Ax.: While it would perhaps be possible for the system to check, when creating the string, whether it's in the intern pool without trying to add it in the event it isn't, the vast majority of strings that get created in most programs aren't going to be in the intern pool.  Checking every generated string against the intern pool on the off chance that a copy of it might be there would generally waste more time than it would save.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of descriptive answers here so I'm not going to repeat what has already been said. What I would like to add is the following code demonstrating all the permutations I can think of. The code is quite long due to the number of combinations. Feel free to drop it into MSTest and see the output for yourself (the output is included at the bottom).

This evidence supports Jon Skeet's answer.

Code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void StringEqualsMethodVsOperator()
{
    string s1 = new StringBuilder("string").ToString();
    string s2 = new StringBuilder("string").ToString();

    Debug.WriteLine("string a = \"string\";");
    Debug.WriteLine("string b = \"string\";");

    TryAllStringComparisons(s1, s2);

    s1 = null;
    s2 = null;

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat("-", 20)));
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    Debug.WriteLine("string a = null;");
    Debug.WriteLine("string b = null;");

    TryAllStringComparisons(s1, s2);
}
private void TryAllStringComparisons(string s1, string s2)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    Debug.WriteLine("-- string.Equals --");
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    Try((a, b) => string.Equals(a, b), s1, s2);
    Try((a, b) => string.Equals((object)a, b), s1, s2);
    Try((a, b) => string.Equals(a, (object)b), s1, s2);
    Try((a, b) => string.Equals((object)a, (object)b), s1, s2);

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    Debug.WriteLine("-- object.Equals --");
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    Try((a, b) => object.Equals(a, b), s1, s2);
    Try((a, b) => object.Equals((object)a, b), s1, s2);
    Try((a, b) => object.Equals(a, (object)b), s1, s2);
    Try((a, b) => object.Equals((object)a, (object)b), s1, s2);

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    Debug.WriteLine("-- a.Equals(b) --");
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    Try((a, b) => a.Equals(b), s1, s2);
    Try((a, b) => a.Equals((object)b), s1, s2);
    Try((a, b) => ((object)a).Equals(b), s1, s2);
    Try((a, b) => ((object)a).Equals((object)b), s1, s2);

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    Debug.WriteLine("-- a == b --");
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    Try((a, b) => a == b, s1, s2);
#pragma warning disable 252
    Try((a, b) => (object)a == b, s1, s2);
#pragma warning restore 252
#pragma warning disable 253
    Try((a, b) => a == (object)b, s1, s2);
#pragma warning restore 253
    Try((a, b) => (object)a == (object)b, s1, s2);
}
public void Try<T1, T2, T3>(Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3>> tryFunc, T1 in1, T2 in2)
{
    T3 out1;

    Try(tryFunc, e => { }, in1, in2, out out1);
}
public bool Try<T1, T2, T3>(Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3>> tryFunc, Action<Exception> catchFunc, T1 in1, T2 in2, out T3 out1)
{
    bool success = true;
    out1 = default(T3);

    try
    {
        out1 = tryFunc.Compile()(in1, in2);
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", tryFunc.Body.ToString(), out1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1} - {2}", tryFunc.Body.ToString(), ex.GetType().ToString(), ex.Message);
        success = false;
        catchFunc(ex);
    }

    return success;
}
```

Output:

```
string a = "string";
string b = "string";

-- string.Equals --

Equals(a, b): True
Equals(Convert(a), b): True
Equals(a, Convert(b)): True
Equals(Convert(a), Convert(b)): True

-- object.Equals --

Equals(a, b): True
Equals(Convert(a), b): True
Equals(a, Convert(b)): True
Equals(Convert(a), Convert(b)): True

-- a.Equals(b) --

a.Equals(b): True
a.Equals(Convert(b)): True
Convert(a).Equals(b): True
Convert(a).Equals(Convert(b)): True

-- a == b --

(a == b): True
(Convert(a) == b): False
(a == Convert(b)): False
(Convert(a) == Convert(b)): False
--------------------

string a = null;
string b = null;

-- string.Equals --

Equals(a, b): True
Equals(Convert(a), b): True
Equals(a, Convert(b)): True
Equals(Convert(a), Convert(b)): True

-- object.Equals --

Equals(a, b): True
Equals(Convert(a), b): True
Equals(a, Convert(b)): True
Equals(Convert(a), Convert(b)): True

-- a.Equals(b) --

a.Equals(b): System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
a.Equals(Convert(b)): System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Convert(a).Equals(b): System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Convert(a).Equals(Convert(b)): System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

-- a == b --

(a == b): True
(Convert(a) == b): True
(a == Convert(b)): True
(Convert(a) == Convert(b)): True
```

Answer (score 3):

It is clear that `tvi.header` is not a `String`. The `==` is an operator that is overloaded by `String` class, which means it will be working only if compiler knows that both side of the operator are `String`.