# String comparison : operator==() vs. Equals()

Tags: c#, string, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/c-are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same)

For string comparison, which approach is better (and safe):

```
string s1="Sarfaraz";
string s2="Nawaz";

bool result1 = (s1==s2) ;//approach 1
bool result2 = s1.Equals(s2) ;//approach 2
```

Or both are same under the hood?

Comment: It depends if you consider "dog" and "Dog" to be the same word, while you can manipulate the string in your first approach using String.Equals(S1,S2,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) can be handy and elegant.

Comment: one warning is that if the strings are null you will throw an exception.  Of course they if you are comparing their value then your expecting a value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like `Equals()` because the available `StringComparison` option is very useful.

The `==` and `!=` operators are based on **the value**, so they are safe to use, even though `String` is a reference type.

Comment: Also worth mentioning if `s1` is `null` the results will differ.