# String Compare Issue

Tags: .net, string, c#-4.0, string-comparison

I have two strings that i want to compare.

`A` is a Silverlight user control with the property `Header`.

`B` is a plain `System.String`.

When i compare like so:

```
if(A.Header == B)
```

I’m getting that they are not the same.

If I inspect the values in VS2010 with quick watch the values are the same. If I run `GetType` on both the objects, I find they are both `System.String`.

I know that i can just compare them with `String.Compare`.

I though that doing `==` on strings would always compare the values. Is there something a bit weird with this Silverlight control I am using? Could anyone explain what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `String.compare` return `true`?

Comment: Does `string.Compare` return that the strings are equal?

Comment: no i just double checked

Comment: Have you considered that the strings are not exactly the same? Perhaps they differ in terms of spacing; try `Trim`.

Comment: they are deffently the same :D

Comment: What do the actual values look like? Are we dealing with canonical forms etc? Unicode issues are possible.

Comment: Then this seems to defy all of the simple explanations, and most of the complicated ones too. I wonder Silverlight may be a factor here...

Comment: yeah i starting to think it might be some thing to do with the control im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer it looks like the equals has been overrided in the silverlight control i am using.

thanks to john in this thread for giving me the answer

[Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/c-are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same)

Answer (score 0):

Do they have same length ? Maybe there is trailing or leading space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char[] arrayA = A.Header.ToCharArray();
char[] arrayB = B.ToCharArray();
```

and inspect them with VS. It should appear clear where they differ.

Comment: This is **not correct**. The `==` operator is overloaded for `String` types to test for value equality, rather than reference equality. It has generally identical meaning to the `==` operator. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/c-are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same) for an overview of the nuances.

Comment: That's not true. Operator == is implemented using Equals() method and compares both sides using theirs values. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx

Comment: Removed downvote in response to your edit. I'll leave my comment just for clarification to anyone else who might think the same thing.

Comment: @Cody ok. Thank you & Nenad for the infos, I was really wrong on that!

Comment: You're welcome. We're all just here to learn something (or at least I am!). And it's a common mistake, since that's how every other reference types work. `String` is a bit of an odd-ball in that (and many other regards).

Answer (score 0):

They might have trailing space or something that looks the same, but has different actual character codes.  Like a Cyrillic character `е` might look like Latin `e`, but they are not the same.  Try to iterate over the characters and see if they all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Might be leading or trailing spaces, difference in casing, maybe it contains characters that look the same, but have a different character code.

Try the following:

```
if (string.Compare(A.Header.Trim(), B.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
{
  ..
}
```

Comment: A more appropriate way to compare the strings would be with the static [string.Compare(a, b, compare)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx) method.