# C# string comparsion methods

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same)

string class provides different methods for comparsion

1. ==
2. `string.Equals`
3. `string.Compare`

what is the difference between == and `Equals` with respect to the string class?

because Equals method is provide by the System.Object which compares the refernces of the objects

Answer (score 2):

In case of string , though it is a reference type , both == and Equals does a value checking unlike other reference types.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [C# String Equals](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals)