# Difference between Object.Equals(objA, objB), objA.Equals(objB) and objA == objB for CLR types?

Tags: c#, .net, iequatable, equals-operator, object-equality

I am wondering if the CLR types would return different results from the following:

```
Object.Equals(objA, objB)

objA.Equals(objB)

(objA == objB)
```

I do realize that outside of the CLR someone could easily implement the `IEqualtable` Equals and overload the == operator improperly. I'm not concerned with people *improperly* implementing these. What I'm concerened with is the classes (including String, Int32, etc) implement these 3 differently.

Also, which one should be the one used for comparison overall (across the board) if that is possible. I wonder this because I ran across a file that uses `Object.Equals(objA, objB)` all over a view-model instead of the other two.

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_name, value)) return;
        ...
    }
}

private int _id;
public int Id
{
    get { return _id; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_id, value)) return;
        ...
    }
}

private Object _obj;
public Object TheObject
{
    get { return _obj; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_obj, value)) return;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object.Equals(a,b) is null safe. It can answer e.g. Equals(null, null) which is true. Apart from that, it just calls the regular Equals() method. As far as I know the clr string and primitive types have equality operators defined that work exactly like Object.Equals(a,b).

For non-null objA and objB, Object.Equals(objA, objB), objA.Equals(objB) and objB.Equals(objA) should be equivalent if the Equals method is correctly implemented.

The use of Equals(_obj, value) seems correct in the code you posted.

If you want the complete list of equality comparisons, don't forget about objA.ReferenceEquals(objB) which is a kind of equality that is useful in many scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

For any floating point number `Equals` and `==` behave differently.

- `NaN==NaN => false` following IEEE logic
- `NaN.Equals(NaN) => true` Follwing the requirement that anything must be equal to itself.

And of course `Equals` is overridden i.e. it works even when the static type is a base type, whereas `==` is overloaded and only works if the static type has been overloaded.

I almost never call `x.Equals(y)` directly. For one it doesn't handle a `x` being `null`, and it's asymmetry is ugly IMO. The static `object.Equals(x,y)` calls the virtual `object.Equals(y)` method, but adds null handling.

`IEquatable<T>.Equals(other)` is equivalent to `object.Equals(other)` on all well behaved types, but it avoids boxing in value types.

In conclusion I usually prefer `==` when the static type is known, and `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` with generic types or if the static type doesn't match the runtime type.

---

In your example `Name` and `Id` behave the same way with `==` and `Equals`, since `string` and `int` are sealed.

`TheObject` on the other hand exhibits different behavior with `==` and `Equals` for certain types. For example if you use `string` then `Equals` will use value equality, and `==` will use reference equality.