# Difference between String1.Equals(string2) and string1==string2 C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: String.Equals vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/c-string-equals-vs)
>   [Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same)

sometimes in a condition between two strings, I write:

```
if(string1==string2) //Do something
```

and sometimes I write:

```
if(string1.Equals(string2)) //Do something
```

The problem is sometimes the first one doesn't work, or miswork, is there any difference between the two expressions?

Comment: If `string1` is null, a `NullReferenceException` will occur in the second one.

Comment: When does the first version of the code not work?  Can you provide example operands?

Comment: sorry guys, the suggestion didn't bring that up when I was posting the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one will always work *so long as the compile-time type of both operands is `string`*.

If the compile-time type of either operand is anything other than `string`, it will use the normal reference identity comparison, rather than comparing strings for equality. Basically you want to call the `==(string, string)` overload instead of the normal `==(object, object)` overload.

Note that the first will succeed even if `string1` is null, whereas the second will throw `NullReferenceException` in that case. An alternative in order to preserve the `Equals` call but avoiding this problem is to call the [static `object.Equals(object, object)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx):

```
if (object.Equals(string1, string2))
```

Personally I'd just use `==` in cases where the compile-time types are appropriate though.

Comment: String.Equals() also has an overload for StringComparison, which gives you a bit more control over how you want the strings compared.  Something to note anyway I guess.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Oh sure, if you're looking for other overloads - I was only talking about the code given, and the equivalent comparison used by the static method.

Comment: `object.==` could be called in scenarios other than the one you mention, e.g. if one of the variables is typed as `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: @Ani: Okay, will edit - basically "if the operands aren't both of type string".

Answer (score -1):

The use of `==` on two string types will perform a reference identity check, meaning it will only return true if both references point to the same object. `Equals` on the other hand is expected to perform a value comparison, and will return true if the references point to objects that are equivalent.

Comment: It can make a huge difference - which is why the compile-time types are important. If you use the overload of `==(string, string)` then that *will* perform a value equality comparison, *not* a reference identity check. It's not clear what you mean by a "simple type" but I suspect you misunderstand something about the `string` type. It's entirely possible to have two equal but distinct instances of `string`, and if you use the `==(object, object)` overload, that *will* return false.

Comment: I think this isn't quite true.  `"cat" == "cat"` will return true even though they are not the same object.  The real difference is `==` will call the static `String` method and `myStr.Equals()` will call the instance method (which is why it fails if the instance is null.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: That's not a good example, because in that case literal interning means that you *are* comparing two copies of the same reference.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sometimes it's tough to account for all of the possible caveats. I think the wording is a little better now. Can you let me know if anything above is incorrect or if I've missed anything?

Comment: @JamesJohnson: It's not at all clear what you mean by "The standard use of `==` on a `string` *type*". If `x` and `y` are `string` variables, then `x == y` will perform the same test as `Equals`.

Comment: Sorry for bugging you about this, but I want to get it right despite the answer having been marked already. Have you discussed this anywhere before, or do you know of any good articles that discuss this topic? I'm also interested in an example where two distinct instances of string could evaluate to false. I appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: Two distinct instances of string will be compared by reference equality if you compare variables which aren't of type `string`. For example: `object x = new StringBuilder("foo").ToString(); object y = new StringBuilder("foo").ToString(); bool z = x == y;` Now `z` will be false, because it will use the `==(object, object)` overload and just compare references.

Comment: As for other bits of writing about it - check out the duplicate questions linked from this one.

Comment: Oh, I see what you were saying now. I thought you meant something else. That makes sense. Thanks :)