# String equals does not work with string formatted numbers

Tags: c#, unit-testing, string-formatting

How can my strings have different hash codes but the same text value of "16 777 216"?

The test method does not pass:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestStringEquals
{
  [TestClass]
  public class FormatterTests
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Double_Test_1()
    {
      Assert.AreEqual("16 777 216", FormatDoubleWithThousandSeparator(16777216, 0));
    }

    public string FormatDoubleWithThousandSeparator(double value, int digits)
    {
      double result = Math.Round((double)value, digits);

      System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo nfi = (System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.Clone();
      nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

      return result.ToString("###,###,###,###,###,###,##0.#####", nfi);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the Math.Round call?

Comment: There's also no need to cast a `double` to a `double`. You don't want to end up with a quadruple.

Comment: you can check jon skeets reply
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same

Comment: I tried to simplify my test as much as I could, I know that I should only test one thing in a unit test method.

Comment: What exception do you get? Your updated code works correctly.

Comment: Failed Double_Test_1 UnitTestStringEquals Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<16 777 216>. Actual:<16 777 216>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the two strings are not the same object, thus they are not equal, there is a string comparision method that should be used instead.

Make sure this isn't the case one string has a non-printing character and the other one does not.  You have to remember that a string is an object.  So you need to compare the value of said object to the value of another object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325.aspx

Comment: Totally. And you (Jonas) should use Assert.Equals : it calls the .Equals method if you pass an object to it (as opposed to Assert.AreSimilar)

Comment: Documentation for the equality operator on strings says that it is implemented using the Equals function, so the results should be the same.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx

Comment: This answered was more geared towards the reason his current unit test is failing. It provides a means to use his current test, compare two **Strings** the correct way, with the least amount of work. I agree that if **Assert.Equals()** is the way to compare two **String** objects then thats what he should use.  I was going to verify how this method works, then I realized that, Redgates .NET Reflector was not installed on the machine I was looking at.

Comment: Assert.IsTrue(String.Compare("16 777 216", FormatDoubleWithThousandSeparator(16777216, 0)) == 0); Didn't work, it may be the case that there are a none printing character in the string.

Comment: The spaces are different. "16 777 216"[6] -> 160 and FormatDoubleWithThousandSeparator(16777216, 0)[6] -> 32. The odd thing about this is that when I change the test from 16 777 216 to 1 000 the test passes.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the test output is more helpful if you replace your assertion with:

```
Assert.AreEqual("16 777 216", numberToString);
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran that unit test in Visual Studio 2010, and it did pass for me.  It may have to do with some culture setting on your computer, or possibly how the == operator behaves on strings.

edited for clarity

Comment: I copied the test exactly, ran it, and it passed for me, too.

Comment: new version passes for me also

Comment: And now it passes for me also, I can't replicate the error. Either it was a temporary bug or I made some mistake while testing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Assert.IsTrue() accepts two **Object** type arguments.  The == operator for object types checks *reference equality*.  Strings overload the == operator to instead check for value equality, but when you pass the strings to that function you have effectively cast them as objects and forced it to use object's == operator: it's going to check your strings for reference equality, which *may or may not return true* depending on whether the strings are interned.

Instead, use `Assert.AreEqual()` or
`Assert.IsTrue("16 777 216".Equals(numberToString), "Expected 2^24")`.

Comment: Could he not simply use **String.Equals** instead?

Comment: That's essentially what the 2nd example does

Comment: While I agree with using Assert.AreEqual(), the fact that the IsTrue method accepts an object is irrelevant.  The equality will be evaluated first, and then the result will be passed in, as an object.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I appreciate the confirmation of my thought process.  I also didn't actually realized you provided a second example.