# how to decide on a bool operators usage, performance issues vs readability

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-4.0, code-readability, boolean-operations

Having even more than two options to choose from, leads me to question, which one to choose, if  the result / outcome is same.

in `.NET` `C#`  the following conditions are asking same question using different operators, so the question is , what experienced developers use, i tend to assume that ready made operators like `Equals` would go through more processing actions.

When and why would you choose `!` over `Equals`, and both over 'traditional'  `==` ?

```
//bool
if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
{
    //bool
    if (NotAuthorized().Equals(false)) 
    {            
        AppsCtrls.DDLs_Init();

        //bool
        if (CurrSeSn.Raised(Flag.MainDataSet_IsPopulated) == false)
        {
            initALLDataSet(AllDataStColsSelectionMod.doneViaSP);
        }

        custid = RConv.Str2int(Request.QueryString["custid"]);
        username = GetTableData.AsString("name", "tblCustomers", "custid", custid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same

Comment: Well, `!` does read the way logic functions are normally read allowed, "If the page is not a post back" or "if you are not authorized" as opposed to "if the page is a postback is equal to false".

Comment: @Josh Those points are entirely irrelevant as `bool` isn't nullable and can't be extended (so there will be no derived types).

Comment: @Servy As @LoneXcoder learned, the link provides a reason to use `Equals`, which involves advantages that the comparison operator, `==`, does not have. It wasn't a link to answer his question but provide some additional insight. Definitely not *irrelevant*.

Comment: @Josh The reason that `==` wasn't working as the OP thought in that case is because the variable was typed as an `object`, not a `string`.  If it was typed as a `string` it would have worked fine.  On top of that, if it was actual code and not in the immediate window he would have gotten a compiler error for using `==` on both a string and an object, as it's a common error.  Again, it's not really relevant when considering booleans.

Comment: @servy Like I already said, it wasn't an answer to his question, but to provide additional insight. OP asks, When and why would you choose ! over Equals, and both over 'traditional' == ?. The link answers that question, in part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is somewhat subjective...

> "i tend to assume that ready made operators like Equals would go
>   through more processing actions."
>
> " when and why would you choose ! over Equals , And both over
>   'traditional' == "

the `Equals` method as part of an instance of an object is used to check for equality of that instance against another, whilst the `==` and `!=` operators are static and are therefore unbound from any object instance. Instead these are like a special static method that accepts two arguments (of usually the same type) and compares them.

Consider the following example:

```
public class CustomObject
{
    int someValue, anotherValue;    

    public bool Equals(CustomObject obj)
    {
        return (this.someValue == obj.someValue && this.anotherValue == obj.anotherValue);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(CustomObject a, CustomObject b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(CustomObject a, CustomObject b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}
```

In this example, the `Equals` method is used to produce a result of the comparison of values in the `CustomObject` against another instance of the same type. The `==` operator for CustomObject simply calls `Equals` on one of the parameter objects and performs an equality check against the other. The `!=` operator simply negates the `==` and produces the opposite result. Therefore, `==` and `!=` do not have much performance overhead over `Equals`, because they both call that method anyway.

**Best practices:**

if a condition is boolean by nature there is no need to use `Equals`, `!=` or `==`, but you should use `!` to negate a boolean condition.

For example:

```
if(IsPostBack) // this is good

if(IsPostBack == true) // this is unnecessary

if(!IsPostBack) // this is good

if(IsPostBack == false) // this is unnecessary
```

If a condition is not boolean by nature, or you are comparing two boolean values, or you are comparing an enumeration, or other value type then use of `!=` or `==` is acceptable.

For example:

```
if(a == b) // this is good

if(a != b) // this is good
```

If a condition is not boolean by nature and the objects you are comparing do not have the `==` or `!=` operators implemented, then using `Equals` is acceptable. *Note, using `!=` and `==` are prohibited with generics since it is not known at compile time that `!=` or `==` are implemented on the objects represented by the generic objects type parameters.*

For example:

```
if(a.Equals(b)) //this is good

if(!a.Equals(b)) // this is good

if(a.Equals(b) == true) // this is unnecessary
```

Comment: @activwrex Thank you for making the effort to write fine answer

Answer (score 1):

I typically choose the option that is the shortest, ie:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

Or:

```
if (Authorized())
```

Since C# doesn't allow non-boolean expressions in an if statement, this is perfectly clear, so I see no reason for the extra typing.

That being said, this is really purely a matter of convention and preference - there is no performance advantage to using one form over the other.

This is different than C++, for example, where you can use `if (42)`, in which case seeing `if (foo)` isn't enough to know whether `foo` is a boolean, or some other type.  In that scenario, it occasionally makes sense to include the condition check (ie: `if (foo == false)`) as you can then see the type distinctly and make your intentions clear.

Comment: so i guess it's same , when it comes from you, only in your example case i would perfer to make first one be more ... you know for me to know and not missing the! within rest of expression , although in this case usage i would expect it to be there as if ! And Pagepostback was born togethere\

Comment: @LoneXcoder Functionally, they're all the same.  Its purely preference in terms of what you want to type.

Answer (score 0):

Use the first.
Unlike C/C++ where zero/null == false, in C# only boolean value types can be used with the boolean operators, i.e.:

```
int i=1;
if (i) { .... }
```

Will not compile, so there is no need to explicitly test equality of booleans, specially when using descriptive names (IsSomething, HasHappened, NotSomething, etc.)

Comment: The one exception I've found is with nullable booleans.  `if(nullableBool == true)` reads nicer to me than `if(nullableBool??false)` or `if(nullableBool != null && nullableBool.Value)`.