# C# Check if textbox == textbox

Tags: c#, version, auto-update

Why does this not work :

```
            if (This_Ver.Text == New_Ver.Text)
            {
                MAIN_PANEL.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (This_Ver.Text != New_Ver.Text)
            {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("An update has been found!" + Environment.NewLine + "Would you like to download and install it?", "Update found!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                MAIN_PANEL.Visible = false;
                UPDATE_PANEL.Visible = true;
                USERNAME_TEXT.Enabled = false;
                PASSWORD_TEXT.Enabled = false;
                LOGIN_BUTTON.Enabled = false;
                MAIN_PANEL.Visible = false;
                UPDATE_NOW_BUTTON.Enabled = true;
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                UPDATE_NOW_BUTTON.Enabled = true;
                MAIN_PANEL.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

I am trying to compare the new version and the current running version.
It should open the updater panel when the textboxes does not contain the same version.

But It doesn't work. It always opens the updater panel.

EDIT :

value : This_Ver.Text : V1.1.13.1

value : New_Ver.Text  : V1.1.13.1

Comment: First thing first, you do not need to check again, once you are in else block, talking about line 4, it will only have else {...}

Comment: what values you getting at `This_Ver.Text,New_Ver.Text`

Comment: That is because your code never updates `This_Ver.Text`

Comment: It updates This_Ver.Text on form load : This_Ver.Text = Application.CurrentVersion();

Comment: Form.Load Event Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time. Is it possible that your code runs before that? Because your code is ok and it is the most possible issue

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the first if statement and see what the comparison returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below may be it will help you you..

*change your code*

**FROM :**

```
if (This_Ver.Text == New_Ver.Text)
```

**TO :**

```
if (This_Ver.Text.ToUpper().Trim().Equals(This_Ver.Text.ToUpper().Trim()))
```

Comment: This fixed my problem thanks. But I have one last question what does Trim?

Comment: Trim() - is  String function that eliminates leading and trailing whitespace of a string.. try this link for full details... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx

Comment: Hmmm intresting, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pandian: The most common method for string comparisons is using `==` There are small differences in the behavior of using`equal' that the string be non-null. This can be problematic in certain algorithms, but good in others. refer sir jon skeet's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same  and http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals

Comment: @Satindersingh: Yes i agree with you most string comparison methods have `==` and `String.Compare`. but i have mostly used `Equals` in my Program so i have suggest this method too...

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this

```
string value1 = This_Ver.Text.Trim();
string value2 = New_Ver.Text.Trim();
if(value1  == value2 )
 {
   //hide your panel
 }
 else
 {
    // code something
 }
```

if value matches it hides otherwise it goes to `else` part where you do some logic code.

Aslo want to know what values are you getting in `value1,value2` while **debugging** on `IF Condition`

Comment: Thats code is the code I got there now It still doesn't work :S

Comment: @Nobleleader13245: after using trim() u still getiing problm ?

Comment: No your fix works aswell I combined the two fixes thanks you aswell

Answer (score 0):

You must use (This_Ver.Text.Equals(New_Ver.Text)) because == comparator will not work. As in Java, == comparator do object references comparation. In contrast, Equals method compares strings content.

Good Luck.

Comment: == comparator has been overridden for String class.

Comment: You are right Thommas. Thanks you. [Docummentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe(v=vs.100).aspx)