# Function always returns null?

Tags: c#, class, function, foreach, null

This function always returns null. sString is a class with a string "Name" and string "Value" values. Don't ask why I'm not using a regular string-- it's complicated. here's my function:

```
static string Get_sString(string VarName, ref List<sString> VarList)
{
    foreach (sString TestsString in VarList)
    {
        if (TestsString.Name == VarName)
        {
            return TestsString.Name;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It's supposed to return the instance with the same Name value as VarName, and it works, except for the if statement *always is false*. I can't figure out why. I actually have an almost identical class called sDecimal, where the only difference is the Value property is a decimal, not a string. The Get_sDecimal() works perfectly fine with that, and the only difference between Get_sDecimal() and Get_sString() are that one tests sDecimal and one tests sString.
**Thanks!**

EDIT:
Here's sString Class.

```
class sString
{
    public string Name;
    public string Value;

    /// <summary>
    /// String Value variables that may have the same name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n">Internal name of variable.</param>
    /// <param name="v">Value of variable.</param>
    public sString(string n, string v)
    {
        Name = n;                    
        Value = v;                    
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's some output code (and output) to clear things up.

```
static string Get_sString(string VarName, ref List<sString> VarList)
        {
            foreach (sString TestsString in VarList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Looking for: " + VarName);
                Console.WriteLine("Comparing with: " + TestsString.Name);
                if (TestsString.Name == VarName)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Match!");
                    return TestsString.Name;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Here's the output:

```
Looking for: Q
Comparing with: Q
```

EDIT: I added a couple more variables to the list. Here's the new output:

```
Looking for: Q
Comparing with: Q
Looking for: Q
Comparing with: Z
Looking for: Q
Comparing with: VariableX
```

Still no Match.

Comment: Can I ask why you are not using a regular Dictionary instead?

Comment: When you break in the code and you manually check VarList, does it actually contain the string you are searching for (remember `==` is case senstive)?

Comment: Yes, it does. I did a check where it printed both the VarName and TestsString.Name on the screen, and both were Identical. It still returned null.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but that `ref` does nothing useful here: that should be removed IMO

Comment: did you try using .Equals() instead of ==

Comment: Can you update the question with `sString` class and how you call `Get_sString` and sample inputs

Comment: What is .Name typed as? Is that a `string`? What are the inputs here: is there actually a match expected?

Comment: Yes, I have. Still returns null.

Comment: I'm editing with a sString.Class.

Comment: the ref is a reference to a list in a seperate class.

Comment: With your update, the most likely answer is that there **simply isn't a match**. Can you show some inputs where this is failing unexpectedly?

Comment: @a_schimpf You're thinking of Java, this is C#

Comment: @cubican if your "the ref is..." relates to the `ref`: that is irrelevant: again - the `ref` here doesn't help you. It isn't the cause of the problem, but it simply isn't needed.

Comment: @cubician and I am still curious about Thilio's original question to you, Why not use a `Dictionary<string,string>` instead?

Comment: `TestsString.Name.Trim().Equals(VarName.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` to be sure there is no case mismatch or white spaces

Comment: @cubician - I took your posted code and wrote a console app to test it, and the function returned the match.  Are you sure there's not a typo or something else going on?  Can you post some sample code where you use the function, and how you populate the List?

Comment: Here's how I'm calling the function, I may be doing it wrong (calling my own function wrong, hardihar XD) : string svalue = Get_sString(name, ref StringVar); where StringVar is a List<sString>.

Comment: Re your example: can you make that: `Console.WriteLine("Looking for: \"" + VarName + "\"");` (and likewise for the other value) - my suspicion is that there is some whitespace involved here - and the two values are not, in fact, equal. `"Q"` != `"Q "`. Of course, it could also be some invisible control/unicode character.

Comment: Why are you using ref again while calling the function cubician? That might be the cause.

Comment: @Jay the `ref` doesn't cause any *actual harm* here; it just makes it bizarre

Comment: @MarcGravell haha I got confused by the use of two ref.

Comment: I added a .Trim(), still doesn't work. Also had it return Value, not Name. Just ignore the ref for now.

Comment: I dunno... I'll just rewrite sString and Get_sString. Whatever.

Comment: @cubician Can you write minimal Console application to recreate this issue? please update the question with that.

Comment: actually, it was some sort of whitespace. I was putting the trim before some other function, so it wasn't trimming it all off. I was having it replace "[str]" with "", but I changed it to replace "[str] " with "". Thanks... what a stupid mistake. :D **Thanks!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code fundamentally works:

```
var list = new List<sString>
{
    new sString("foo", "123"),
    new sString("bar", "456")
};
var s = Get_sString("foo", ref list);
// = "foo", not null
```

Don't get me wrong - I'd change every line of it. But it doesn't always return `null`.

Brief problem list:

- public fields
- unnecessary `ref`
- could just use `Dictionary<string,string>`
- horrible names
- I wonder if you should be returning `.Value` rather than `.Name`

Comment: Yes code does work. I tested it myself. So it should be related to something else. Maybe list is empty somehow.

Comment: @Jay my money is on whitespace

Comment: I'll look for whitespace then. I'll come back if that isn't the case. Thanks!

Comment: I believe so too Marc but why is cubician calling the function like string svalue = Get_sString(name, ref StringVar);? What is ref for?

Comment: @Jay 2 very good points - odd naming and an unnecessary `ref`; which I why I included those very things as bullet items in my answer ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell, That is correct. Sorry I did not notice it at first glance at your bullet-ed answer.

Comment: the sString and sDecimal classes are for variables that are defined and used in a "psuedo program" that my program runs.

Answer (score 2):

You do realize that you have basically re-implemented LINQ:

```
return VarList.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name == VarName);
```

Also your `sString` class could just be a `KeyValuePair<string,string>`

**UPDATE**

Actually, you *said*:

> It's supposed to return the instance with the same Name value as VarName

But it doesn't return an `sString` instance.  Instead, it returns `TestsString.Name` - which is the same string you started with, but only if it's in the list.  So basically, this is a complicated "contains" check.

Comment: you can't quite use *just* `FirstOrDefault` here; the return value needs to be the `.Name`, not the `sString`. And there's nothing wrong with a good honest `foreach` loop ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell - Actually, I see now why I made that mistake.  Read his text right after the code.  I'll update...

Comment: yeah, it could be `return VarList.Any(x => x.Name == VarName) ? VarName : null;` - which is a very odd test to run

Answer (score 1):

You should use String.Equals instead of == operator.

== operator does not always work.
you can find samples in the thread [Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same).

Comment: Since the types are known statically as `==`, there is no good reason to use `Equals` here, and a very good reason not to (`==` avoids issues with `null`) - and a mediocre reason not to (`==` avoids an unnecessary virtual dispatch). Basically, if you know the data types, `==` is usually preferable in .NET