# c# Fastest way to compare strings

Tags: c#, string, performance

I've noticed that

```
string1.Length == string2.Length && string1 == string2
```

on large strings is slightly faster than just

```
string1 == string2
```

Is this true? And is this a good practice to compare large string lengths before comparing actual strings?

Comment: It's not hard to test it, all you need to do is to write it on Console and to use a StopWatch although this is not the most accurate but it enough good for this one. I will do the check and will answer you.

Comment: How did you *notice* that? Any facts to backup this notice? Any sample test proving it?

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky It is amazingly hard to test, if by "testing" you also mean "generating a meaningful test input".

Comment: How do you know `string1 == string2` doesn't check the length first?

Comment: Unless you have a benchmark that indicates one is faster than the other **with your specific data**, the proper answer here is "Use whichever is more readable".

Comment: @KenWhite Exactly. I'd disambiguate that statement by saying "which would be the second snippet" :)

Comment: Used a stopwatch and looped a million times each test. On average it was 5 ms when just comparing two strings vs 3 ms when checking lengths of strings first. Of course, the difference is not that big, but still.

Comment: @ConradFrix It actually does ;)

Comment: As an aside you need to be very careful when using `==` on a string see [Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3678792/119477) Null values, empty strings, string interning, diacritical marks, and case sensitivity all  cause problems.

Comment: I work in a 1e6-line c# app. When people wonder about performance, they wonder about things like string-compare, but the actual performance problems we have are *never* in stuff like string-compare. They are in stuff like a) reading resource files to get text to display to users who are wondering what's taking so long :), b) painting windows over and over because the "paint" handler gets added repeatedly but never taken away, c) adding data cells to a worksheet one by one when they could be batched up and done as a group. In other words, I recommend finding out what's *actually* a problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`string`s operator equals does the length check before comparing the chars. So you do not save the comparison of the contents with this trick. You *might* still save a few CPU cycles because your length check assumes that the strings are not null, while the BCL must check that. So if the lengths are not equal most of the time, you will short-circuit a few instructions.

I might just be wrong here, though. Maybe the operator gets inlined and the checks optimized out. Who knows for sure? (He who measures.)

If you care about saving every cycle you can you should probably use a different strategy in the first place. Maybe managed code is not even the right choice. Given that, I recommend to use the shorter form and not use the additional check.

Comment: `So if the lengths are not equal most of the time, you will short-circuit a few instructions.` And now it's a statistics problem

Comment: Yes this is most likely why I've noticed the very slight performance difference when looping a million times, it just skipped the null check for both values, saving a few cycles. The difference is too insignificant to put an extra line there.

Comment: According to the reference source, the `string` operator overload `==` calls `String.Equals()`, which only raises more questions about the observed difference in performance...

Comment: Presumably you also avoid the overhead of a method call when using `==` on `String.Length`s.

Answer (score 19):

[String.Equality Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx) or  `==` internally calls `string.Equals`, so use [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx) or `==` provided by the framework. It is already optimized enough.

It first compare references, then length and then actual characters.

You can find the source code [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/String@cs/1305376/String@cs)

Code: (Source: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/String@cs/1305376/String@cs)

```
// Determines whether two strings match.
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == null)                        //this is necessary to guard against reverse-pinvokes and
        throw new NullReferenceException();  //other callers who do not use the callvirt instruction

    String str = obj as String;
    if (str == null)
        return false;

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        return true;

    return EqualsHelper(this, str);
}
```

and

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
private unsafe static bool EqualsHelper(String strA, String strB)
{
    Contract.Requires(strA != null);
    Contract.Requires(strB != null);
    int length = strA.Length;
    if (length != strB.Length) return false;

    fixed (char* ap = &strA.m_firstChar) fixed (char* bp = &strB.m_firstChar)
    {
        char* a = ap;
        char* b = bp;

        // unroll the loop
#if AMD64
        // for AMD64 bit platform we unroll by 12 and
        // check 3 qword at a time. This is less code
        // than the 32 bit case and is shorter
        // pathlength

        while (length >= 12)
        {
            if (*(long*)a     != *(long*)b) break;
            if (*(long*)(a+4) != *(long*)(b+4)) break;
            if (*(long*)(a+8) != *(long*)(b+8)) break;
            a += 12; b += 12; length -= 12;
        }
 #else
        while (length >= 10)
        {
            if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) break;
            if (*(int*)(a+2) != *(int*)(b+2)) break;
            if (*(int*)(a+4) != *(int*)(b+4)) break;
            if (*(int*)(a+6) != *(int*)(b+6)) break;
            if (*(int*)(a+8) != *(int*)(b+8)) break;
            a += 10; b += 10; length -= 10;
        }
  #endif

        // This depends on the fact that the String objects are
        // always zero terminated and that the terminating zero is not included
        // in the length. For odd string sizes, the last compare will include
        // the zero terminator.
        while (length > 0)
        {
            if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) break;
            a += 2; b += 2; length -= 2;
        }

        return (length <= 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It just compares references unless you pass special options, anyways. That;s because of the string intern pool.

Comment: +1: `==` operator uses `int i = strA.Length;
 if (i != strB.Length)
 {
  return false;
 }`

Comment: No, it compares values. Unless you cast the strings to objects first and use `==`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Scroll down to EqualsHelpers to see that that is what's actually going on!

Comment: @It'sNotALie No, `==`compares the reference AND value. C# is not Java

Comment: None of this code is even reached if the lengths aren't equal.

Comment: BTW, posting that code is probably a copyright violation.  I've been careful not to sign up to view shared source, even though it would be available to me, because I don't want there ever to be a question of creating a derivative.

Comment: @Shoe It doesn't on .NET 4.5 (for me, anyways)

Comment: @BenVoigt, I am not sure about the copy right, If I check the link then Microsoft has its copyright, I have also specified the source, if there is an issue with the copyright, I think Stackoverflow can remove the code.

Answer (score 10):

For the geeks among us, [here's a page](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-compare-strings) which does a great job at benchmarking [numerous ways to compare strings](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-compare-strings).

In a nutshell, the fastest method appears to be the CompareOrdinal:

```
if (string.CompareOrdinal(stringsWeWantToSeeIfMatches[x], stringsWeAreComparingAgainst[x]) == 0)
{
//they're equal
}
```

The second best way seems to be using either a Dictionary or Hashset with the "key" as the string you want to compare.

Makes for an interesting read.

Comment: The link appears to have become broken; it now refers to the current page.

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed the links.

Comment: How old is this info? Is it still the case for DotNet Core?

Comment: @user1034912, yes! You can try it yourself! I just did :)

Answer (score 7):

My test results

**Compare 10000 strings to 10000 other strings all the same length (256)**

Time (s1 == s2): 32536889 ticks

Time (s1.Length == s2.Length) && (s1 == s2): 37380529 ticks

**Compare 10000 strings to 10000 other strings Random length max 256**

Time (s1 == s2): 27223517 ticks

Time (s1.Length == s2.Length) && (s1 == s2): 23419529 ticks

**Compare 10000 strings to 10000 other strings Random length min 256 max 512**

Time (s1 == s2): 28904898 ticks

Time (s1.Length == s2.Length) && (s1 == s2): 25442710 ticks

What I find mind boggling is that a compare of 10000 equal length strings will take longer than comparing the same amount of data that is larger.

All these test have been done with exactly the same data.

Comment: I'm a little late, but the reason that the equal length strings take longer is because the == operator first checks if they are null then checks if they are equal length before checking if the contents are identical. If the lengths are the same, it proceeds; if they are different, it stops there.

Answer (score 4):

According ILSpy, the string `==` operator is defined as:

```
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
    return string.Equals(a, b);
}
```

Which is defined as

```
public static bool Equals(string a, string b)
{
    return a == b || (a != null && b != null && a.Length == b.Length && string.EqualsHelper(a, b));
}
```

I assume that first `a == b` is actually a reference equality check (ILSpy is just rendering it as `==`), otherwise this would be an infinitely recursive method.

This means that `==` already checks the lengths of the strings before actually comparing their characters.

Comment: This is what `ILSPy` yields for me(.NET 4, the length check is in `EqualsHelper`): `public static bool Equals(string a, string b)
{
 return a == b || (a != null && b != null && string.EqualsHelper(a, b));
}`

Comment: @TimSchmelter What version of the assembly are you looking at? The posted code is from 4.0.0.0? In 2.0.0.0 I see `return (value != null || this == null) && string.EqualsHelper(this, value);`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is indeed strange. I can distinctly see calls to `System.String::get_Length()` in the IL. And yes, I see *another* length check inside `EqualsHelper`.

Answer (score 3):

In terminated strings, it makes sense to just start comparing characters, since you can't calculate the string lengths without iterating all characters anyway, and the comparison is likely to early exit.

With length-counted strings, comparing the length should be done first, **if you are testing for byte-wise equality**.  You can't even start accessing character data without retrieving the length, since one could be zero-length.

If you are doing a relational comparison, knowing the lengths are different doesn't tell you if the result should be positive or negative.  And in a culture-aware comparison, equal strings do not imply equal lengths.  So for both of those you need to just compare data.

If `operator==(string, string)` simply delegates to a relational comparison, you wouldn't expect that to compare lengths.  Checking length before doing the comparison could therefore be a benefit.  But it seems like the Framework does start with a length check.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the first one is faster is the result of `string1.Length == string2.Length` is false. Thanks to Short Circuit Evalution (SCE) the actual comparision between the strings is then not made, which might save you time.

If the strings are equal however, the first one is slower since it will check the length first and then do the same thing as the second one.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx for information about the `&&` operator and SCE.

Answer (score 0):

So as I promised I wrote a short code with a stopwatch - you can copy paste it and try on different strings and see the differences

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str1 = "put the first value";
        string str2 = "put the second value";
        CompareTwoStringsWithStopWatch(str1, str2); //Print the results.
    }

    private static void CompareTwoStringsWithStopWatch(string str1, string str2)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; i++)
        {
            if (str1.Length == str2.Length && str1 == str2)
            {
                SomeOperation();
            }
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("{0}. Time: {1}", "Result for: str1.Length == str2.Length && str1 == str2", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        stopwatch.Reset();

        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; i++)
        {
            if (str1 == str2)
            {
                SomeOperation();
            }
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("{0}. Time: {1}", "Result for: str1 == str2", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }

    private static int SomeOperation()
    {
        var value = 500;
        value += 5;

        return value - 300;
    }
}
```

My conclusions:

1. As I checked some strings (short ones and long ones) I saw that all the results are almost the same. So the first if (with the length check) is slower in 2/3.
2. And you have an Equals method in the Object class, just use it :)
3. You can try it and give us the results also :)

Answer (score -1):

If you expect the strings to be different in their lenghts in most of the time, you can compare their lenghts **AND** then compare the strings itself by using `string.Compare`. I got almost 50% performance improvement by doing this:

```
if (str1.Length == str2.Length)
{
    if (string.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
    {
       doSomething()
    }
}
```

In this case, I expect the strings to be different almost all the time, I think str1.Lenght is way cheaper than comparing the actual strings. If they are equal in size, I compare them.

**EDIT**: Forget what I said. Just use `==` and be happy.

Comment: String's `==` operator also compares `String.Length` first.

Comment: So I have to check why I got this performance improvement. Maybe it's other thing.