# Textbox input won't generate from array

Tags: c#

```
ArrayList stateList, gdpList, rankList;
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    stateList = new ArrayList(); //The state array list
    stateList.Add("Delaware"); 
    stateList.Add("Alaska");
    stateList.Add("North Dakota");
    stateList.Add("Connecticut");
    stateList.Add("Wyoming");
    stateList.Add("Massachusetts");
    stateList.Add("New York");
    stateList.Add("New Jersey");
    stateList.Add("Oregon");
    stateList.Add("Washington");
    stateList.Add("Virginia");
    stateList.Add("Minnesota");

    rankList = new ArrayList(); //The ranking array list for each state
    rankList.Add(1);
    rankList.Add(2);
    rankList.Add(3);
    rankList.Add(4);
    rankList.Add(5);
    rankList.Add(6);
    rankList.Add(7);
    rankList.Add(8);
    rankList.Add(9);
    rankList.Add(10);
    rankList.Add(11);
    rankList.Add(12);

    gdpList = new ArrayList(); //The GDP array list for each state
    gdpList.Add("61,183");
    gdpList.Add("61,156");
    gdpList.Add("55,250");
    gdpList.Add("54,925");
    gdpList.Add("54,305");
    gdpList.Add("53,221");
    gdpList.Add("53,067");
    gdpList.Add("49,430");
    gdpList.Add("48,069");
    gdpList.Add("47,146");
    gdpList.Add("47,127");
    gdpList.Add("47,028");

}

void GDP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string  state1 = State.Text;
    for (int i = 0; i < stateList.Count; i++ )
    {
        if (state1 == stateList[i])
        {
            Response.Write("The " + stateList[i] + " state GDP is " + gdpList[i] + " and the rank is " + rankList[i]);
        }
        else if (state1 == stateList[i])
        {
            Response.Write("The state that you entered is not a part of our state list");
        }
    }
}
```

So I have these three arrays. 
One with twelve states, one with ranking of 1-12, and their GDP in the other array. There is a text box and a button. If you enter say.. Delaware in the text box, then click the button it will generate a label that says: the state, their rank, and their GDP. However, regardless of what state I put in it will always return "the state is not listed" even if it matches the array. I'm assuming that the loop keeps running. So I tried, adding break after each response, that didn't work. Then I tried, adding return after each response, that didn't work either. I tried boolean but couldn't exactly figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Your `if` and `else if` conditions are identical.

Comment: why are you using an `ArrayList` why not just use `List<T> where T is a string` so something like this `List<string> stateList = new List<string()`

Comment: Why iterate through, you can simply do: `stateList.Contains(state1)`.  Which if it exist will return true, otherwise false.

Comment: Tim, that was a mistype. I meant to do != instead of ==. 
Austin, yes I did.
Greg where do you put that

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions within your loop check for the same thing.  And, if the second condition executed when there was no match, you'd still be writing to the response for every item within your stateList collection.

Instead, Try:

```
void GDP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string  state1 = State.Text;
    bool foundMatch = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < stateList.Count; i++ )
    {
        if (state1 == stateList[i])
        {
            Response.Write("The " + stateList[i] + " state GDP is " + gdpList[i] + " and the rank is " + rankList[i]);
            foundMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!foundMatch)
    {
        Response.Write("The state that you entered is not a part of our state list");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I tried the code you posted, and every time I enter say "Delaware" again, it still gives me that "the state you entered is not a part"

Answer (score 0):

Your condition for the `else` is exactly the same as the `if` condition.

I think you refactor your code like

```
void GDP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string  state1 = State.Text;
    for (int i = 0; i < stateList.Count; i++ )
    {
        if (state1 == stateList[i])
        {
            Response.Write("The " + stateList[i] + 
               " state GDP is " + gdpList[i] + " and the rank is " + rankList[i]);
            return;
        }
    }

    Response.Write("The state that you entered is not a part of our state list");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much easier way of doing what you are trying to do notice the different way that I have Initialized the List and List now you can use this as a learning tool as a more efficient way do doing what you have coded.. if you want to break out of the code when it's not in the list then you will need to add the `break;` after this line

`Response.Write(string.Format("The {0} state GDP is {1} and the rank is {2} " ,stateList[i], gdpList[i], rankList[i]));` if you are expected to return a boolean I would either alter the method or I would create a Property that you can access outside of the method you're currently in

```
var stateList = new List<string>
{
 "Delaware",
 "Alaska",
 "North Dakota",
 "Connecticut",
 "Wyoming",
 "Massachusetts",
 "New York",
 "New Jersey",
 "Oregon",
 "Washington",
 "Virginia",
 "Minnesota"
};

var rankList = new List<int>
{
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
};

var gdpList = new List<string>
{
    "61,183",
    "61,156",
    "55,250",
    "54,925",
    "54,305",
    "53,221",
    "53,067",
    "49,430",
    "48,069",
    "47,146",
    "47,127",
    "47,028"
};
var bFound = false;
string state1 = State.Text;
for (int i = 0; i < stateList.Count; i++)
{
    if (state1.Contains(stateList[i]))
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("The {0} state GDP is {1} and the rank is {2} " ,stateList[i], gdpList[i], rankList[i]));
     bFound = true;
     break;
    }
}
if (!bFound)
{
    Response.Write("The state that you entered is not a part of our state list");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code inside `GDP_Click` method into:

```
string state1 = State.Text;
for (int i = 0; i < stateList.Count; i++)
{
    if (state1.Equals(stateList[i]))
    {
        Response.Write("The " + stateList[i] + " state GDP is " + gdpList[i] + " and the rank is " + rankList[i]);
        return;
    }
}
Response.Write("The state that you entered is not a part of our state list");
```

---

### EXPLANATION:

Here's the important part: `state1.Equals(stateList[i])`

**Why `==` doesn't work?**

`ArrayList` is a non-generic collection that returning an boxed `Object` type when you retrieve element(s) from it. So when performing `state1 == stateList[i]` that means you are comparing a `String` type against `Object` type, **not** `String` against `String` anymore, so the comparison will be performed as `Object` reference comparison (whether two operands refer to the same object)

Keep in mind that `==` operator and `Equals` methods are different. If you sure that two instance that you will compare are the same specific type, that it's safe to use `==` operator. Otherwise, if one of the instance is boxed into `Object` type, than **I suggest you to use `Equals` method instead**.

*) futher reading:

- [C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)
- [Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same)

Consider this code:

```
object a = 123;
object b = 123;
```

`a == b` will always return **false**, even when they contain the same integer. Because comparing two `Object` type will do a reference comparison, instead of the content of object itself.

but `a.Equals(b)` or `b.Equals(a)` will able to return true. Or even better to use `Equals(a, b)` (shortcut from `Object.Equals(a, b)`), the latest form will avoid the `NullReferenceException` if `a` or `b` is `null`.