# Object Equals - whats the basic logic for pure objects or reference types that don't override Equals?

Tags: c#, .net

I got here after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same) and I didn't find a relevant answer - So please don't mark this as a duplicate until you read the whole question.

I've been using a reflector and looked into `Object.Equals`.What I saw is:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public virtual bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return RuntimeHelpers.Equals(this, obj);
}
```

And `RuntimeHelpers.Equals` looks like this:

```
// System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers
/// <summary>Determines whether the specified <see cref="T:System.Object" /> instances are considered equal.</summary>
/// <returns>true if the <paramref name="o1" /> parameter is the same instance as the <paramref name="o2" /> parameter, or if both are null, or if o1.Equals(o2) returns true; otherwise, false.</returns>
/// <param name="o1">The first object to compare. </param>
/// <param name="o2">The second object to compare. </param>
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public new static extern bool Equals(object o1, object o2);
```

Now I can't see the implementation of `RuntimeHelpers.Equals` but by the description, if both objects aren't the same instance and aren't null it will call the `object.Equals` method again and I'd get into a loop (I'm talking about **pure objects**).

When I say pure objects I mean something like this:

```
object pureObj1 = new object();
object pureObj2 = new object();
bool areEql = pureObj1.Equals(pureObj2);
```

By documentation this should call `Object.Equals` and get a **recusive stackoverflow**. I guess maybe the documentation is wrong and this checks **reference equality** for basic objects - but I wanted to be sure.

**Bottom line:**
When comparing two pure objects(e.g. not casting a string into on object) via an `Equals` call - how does it determine if they are equal? - What happens if I don't override the `Equals` method and I call `Equals` on two objects? 

P.s. is there anyway that I can see the `RuntimeHelpers.Equals` source code?

Comment: As an aside, there's no need to use reflectors for this anymore, you can use [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,517682d5f6f4f8b4)

Comment: Unfortunately, the 2.0 SSCLI does not have an "ecall" for RH.Equals. This seems to be a newer construct. Impossible to look at what this method does. Probably, it checks if `obj.GetType() == typeof(object)` and short-circuits the comparison.

Comment: We will only find out for sure when the .NET CLR source code is published (which appears to be slated). Or, when Hans Passant takes note of this question.

Comment: Where does the description of `RuntimeHelpers.Equals` come from? I don't get it out of Reflector and I don't see it in http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/runtimehelpers.cs,163 and I don't get it when using intellisence on that method.

Comment: Someone send Hans a bat signal!

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @Chris - I used ILSpy version 2.2.0.1706 and saw the comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[MSDN's page on `object.Equals(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47) covers this in some detail. Specifically, the default implementation for reference types is reference equality. The table in the section "Notes for Inheritors" is the most direct.

> Reference equality; equivalent to calling Object.ReferenceEquals.

[MSDN's page on `RuntimeHelpers.Equals(object,object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edy4ke1e) does say that `Object.Equals(Object)` is called in the case that its arguments are not reference equal and neither is null. This is demonstrably false; the behavior actually exhibited is that **`RuntimeHelpers.Equals(object,object)` never calls `Object.Equals(Object)`**.

For example, this LINQPad script:

```
void Main()
{
    object left = new Foo();
    object right = new Foo();
    left.Equals(right).Dump();
    RuntimeHelpers.Equals( left, right ).Dump();
    left = new Bar();
    right = new Bar();
    left.Equals(right).Dump();
    RuntimeHelpers.Equals( left, right ).Dump();
    left = new Baz();
    right = new Baz();
    left.Equals(right).Dump();
    RuntimeHelpers.Equals( left, right ).Dump();
    left = new Qux();
    right = new Qux();
    left.Equals(right).Dump();
    RuntimeHelpers.Equals( left, right ).Dump();
}

private class Foo {}

private class Bar {
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { 
        "Bar.Equals() called".Dump();
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}

private class Baz {
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { 
        "Baz.Equals() called".Dump();
        return RuntimeHelpers.Equals( this, obj );
    }
}

private class Qux {
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { 
        "Qux.Equals() called".Dump();
        return true;
    }
}
```

prints the output below:

> False
>
> False
>
> Bar.Equals() called
>
> False
>
> False
>
> Baz.Equals() called
>
> False
>
> False
>
> Qux.Equals() called
>
> True
>
> False

So I cribbed a little from [an answer Hans Passant gave about `Math.Pow()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework/8870593#8870593)...

This is the relevant code from \clr\src\vm\ecall.cpp in [SSCLI2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4917)

```
FCFuncStart(gObjectFuncs)
    FCIntrinsic("GetType", ObjectNative::GetClass, CORINFO_INTRINSIC_Object_GetType)
    FCFuncElement("InternalGetHashCode", ObjectNative::GetHashCode)
    FCFuncElement("InternalEquals", ObjectNative::Equals)
    FCFuncElement("MemberwiseClone", ObjectNative::Clone)
FCFuncEnd()
```

This is the code for the function in \clr\src\vm\comobject.cpp to which it is mapped:

```
FCIMPL2(FC_BOOL_RET, ObjectNative::Equals, Object *pThisRef, Object *pCompareRef)
{
    CONTRACTL
    {
        THROWS;
        DISABLED(GC_NOTRIGGER);
        INJECT_FAULT(FCThrow(kOutOfMemoryException););
        MODE_COOPERATIVE;
        SO_TOLERANT;          
    }
    CONTRACTL_END;
    
    if (pThisRef == pCompareRef)    
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(TRUE);

    // Since we are in FCALL, we must handle NULL specially.
    if (pThisRef == NULL || pCompareRef == NULL)
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(FALSE);

    MethodTable *pThisMT = pThisRef->GetMethodTable();

    // If it's not a value class, don't compare by value
    if (!pThisMT->IsValueClass())
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(FALSE);

    // Make sure they are the same type.
    if (pThisMT != pCompareRef->GetMethodTable())
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(FALSE);

    // Compare the contents (size - vtable - sink block index).
    BOOL ret = memcmp(
        (void *) (pThisRef+1), 
        (void *) (pCompareRef+1), 
        pThisRef->GetMethodTable()->GetBaseSize() - sizeof(Object) - sizeof(int)) == 0;

    FC_GC_POLL_RET();

    FC_RETURN_BOOL(ret);
}
FCIMPLEND
```

I see the reference comparison, null checks, value type exclusion, type match check, and a bitwise equality comparison. I don't see how `Object.Equals(Object)` is ever called. I believe that the documentation for `RuntimeHelpers.Equals(object,object)` is simply incorrect.

Comment: This article does not cover RuntimeHelpers.Equals.

Comment: The question is "whats the basic logic for pure objects or reference types that don't override Equals?". RuntimeHelpers is an implementation detail.

Comment: I've got to agree with Jude here. The question asks what the correct logic for equals is and the stuff about `RuntimeHelpers` is just the OPs attempt to understand it which doesn't matter.

Comment: @Chris It seems to matter to the OP - and I'm quite intrigued as well

Comment: +1 - That's pretty much what I thought happens. Anyway it would be nice to see some source code if someone has access to it somehow..

Comment: @dcastro: I do think it is more interesting but it isn't what the question asked (it very explicitly put that as a PS in the bottom line rather than the main question) so it seems harsh to give a -1 for not addressing the RuntimeHelper stuff (I assume usr's comment on it not covering RuntimeHelpers was the reason for the -1, whether or not it was actually usr that did it).

Comment: I downvoted both answers because as they stand they simply do not answer the question. This is a primary situation for a downvote. Trivial guesses without evidence do not bring clarity.

Comment: Documentation is not a guess. Executing sample code is not a guess. The behavior is clearly observable. There's a minor error in the wording of the MSDN page for one implemented-in-the-runtime method used to implement the method the question is actually about, but that doesn't make my answer is a guess.

Comment: The documentation clearly calls out a different behavior than what is observed. What's the explanation for that in your mind? I don't see any here.

Comment: How does the runtime detect recursion in the Baz case? I could imagine the runtime finding that Equals is overridden, calling it and reentering the recursive loop. (Probably, the same can happen in the Bar case.) I think this is an interesting test case but what exactly happens is still unknown.

Comment: @usr The actual question is about behavior not cause. An explanation would be nice, but the result is the actual answer. (Incidentally, sorry for renaming cases under you, but I see you edited to correct for that.)

Comment: @usr I think my explanation is now quite complete.

Comment: The SSCLI code posted here does not seem to cover RH.Equals. I read this code, too. This seems to be the ecall for Object.Equals. I suspect if one were to install a 2.0 runtime the equality system worked differently. (In fact it completely eludes me why RH.Equals is not implemented in managed code in 3 lines or so.)

Comment: I upvoted this. I think this covers enough ground to be useful. When the CLR is eventually open-sourced we can take another look.

Comment: I upvoted and accepted this answer. Thank you very much for your help. We will need to wait for the CLR to be open-sourced to verify this - but this is good enough.

Answer (score 6):

`Object.Equals` is *virtual*. Types override it to have different behaviour.

The default implementation, as you note, calls to an `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` method (ie. it is part of the .NET runtime's internals). This method performs reference equality by directly looking at the reference (essentially it does a C/C++ pointer comparison).

There is no recursion.

NB. The documentation for [`ReferenceHelper.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edy4ke1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> **true** if the o1 parameter is the same instance as the o2 parameter, or if both are **null**, or if `o1.Equals(o2)` returns **true;** otherwise, **false**.

(Emphasis from the source.)

But this would imply that `a.Equals(b)` where `Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)` is false and neither are `null`, then `Object.Equals(object)` calls `ReferenceHelper.Equals(object, object)` calls `Object.Equals(object)`, …. This seems to be a documentation error (runtime behaviour is not recursive for types not overriding `Equals(object)` and then called for different objects resulting in a `false` reference equality result).

Comment: I wrote the same answer but the docs for RH.Equals state that it does call Object.Equals, which clearly calls RH.Equals.

Comment: So are you saying that basically the comment is wrong about it calling `o1.Equals(o2)`?

Comment: @usr Read that sentence from [`ReferenceHelps.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edy4ke1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) again: note it starts with "true if the o1 parameter is the same instance as the o2 parameter": it checks for reference equality *first*.

Comment: @Chris: see my previous comment.

Comment: @Richard What if reference comparison fails (e.g., `pureObj1.Equals(pureObj2)`)? The comment suggests that, in that case, `object.Equals` would be called next, leading  to this recursive call.

Comment: @Richard comparing two different objects should still result in a loop.

Comment: I think @usr is right, the code probably checks if the first argument is of type `Object` and, if so, does not call `object.Equals` and returns false if reference comparison fails.

Comment: +1 - That's pretty much what I thought happens. Anyway it would be nice to see some source code if someone has access to it somehow..

Comment: @dcastro It's actually not that simple of a rule, as the sample in my answer shows.

Comment: @Richard, there is no recursion in the overrides-but-calls-base case, either.

Comment: @JudeM: Correct, will fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion elsewhere on this page. Please notice that ***there's a difference between numbers 3 and 4!***. Another point that is easily mistaken is that the `base.Equals` instance method (#1) calls `RuntimeHelpers.Equals` version, and *not* its own static method `Object.ReferenceEquals`.

1. > [virtual bool **((Object)**​*this*​**).Equals**(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals#System_Object_Equals_System_Object_)
   > <sup>[[link to source]](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/44be29be67bd57a2f70838d9fb608a164717ab08/src/mscorlib/src/System/Object.cs#L60-L63)</sup>
   >
   > ```
   > [__DynamicallyInvokable]
   > public virtual bool Equals(object obj) => RuntimeHelpers.Equals(this, obj);
   > ```
   >
   > This is the instance method in the `Object` base class. As noted above, this avoids infinite recursion by calling the `RuntimeHelpers` version which cannot be overridden.
2. > [static bool **Object.Equals**(Object, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals#System_Object_Equals_System_Object_System_Object_)
   > <sup>[[link to source]](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/44be29be67bd57a2f70838d9fb608a164717ab08/src/mscorlib/src/System/Object.cs#L65-L76)</sup>
   >
   > ```
   > public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB)
   > {
   >    if (objA == objB)
   >        return true;
   >
   >    if (objA == null || objB == null)
   >        return false;
   >
   >    return objA.Equals(objB);
   > }
   > ```
3. > [static bool **Object.ReferenceEquals**(Object, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals)
   > <sup>[[link to source]](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/44be29be67bd57a2f70838d9fb608a164717ab08/src/mscorlib/src/System/Object.cs#L78-L82)</sup>
   >
   > ```
   > [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
   > [NonVersionable, __DynamicallyInvokable]
   > public static bool ReferenceEquals(Object objA, Object objB)
   > {
   >     return objA == objB;
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > Results in the simplest runtime code. Usually ends up inlined with a trivial CPU comparison of the handle values for the two reference types. Does not call user-defined `Equals` overrides and makes no attempt to equate non reference-types by any means. That is, no two value types, blittable primitives, enums, etc. will ever equate.
4. > [static bool **RuntimeHelpers.Equals**(Object, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.equals)
   > <sup>[[link to source]](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/44be29be67bd57a2f70838d9fb608a164717ab08/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.cs#L122-L123)</sup>
   >
   > ```
   > [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), SecuritySafeCritical]
   > public new static extern bool Equals(object o1, object o2);
   > ```
   >
   > Notice the `extern` keyword: there is no IL code; this jumps directly to a CLR-internal code. Also beware that this is a `newslot` static method, so you must qualify this with "`R̲u̲n̲t̲i̲m̲e̲H̲e̲l̲p̲e̲r̲s̲.Equals`" at any call site or you'll get the *very* different behavior of the instance method (#2) `Object.Equals`.
5. > [override bool **((ValueType)**​*this*​**).Equals**(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype.equals)
   > <sup>[[link to source]](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/44be29be67bd57a2f70838d9fb608a164717ab08/src/mscorlib/src/System/ValueType.cs#L25-L67)</sup>
   >
   > (Not shown)
   > Probably subject to JIT interception anyway. May end up at [runtimecallablewrapper.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/44be29be67bd57a2f70838d9fb608a164717ab08/src/vm/runtimecallablewrapper.cpp#L5506-L5535).

There's much more to discuss here. A major factor is that a lot of the behavior is heavily influenced or intercepted by special JIT processing some of which might depend on whether an instance encountered at runtime can possibly be a value type, or whether the JIT can rule that out. I'm no expert on these matters either, so feel free to comment and/or correct. Let me know if there's interest in more detail on the JIT results, and I might be able to expand this a bit.