# Overriding Equals(): is null comparison redundant when calling base.Equals()?

Tags: c#, inheritance, equality

When overriding the `Equals()` method, the [MSDN recommends this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.80).aspx):

```
class Point: Object {
   protected int x, y;

   public Point(int X, int Y) {
      this.x = X;
      this.y = Y;
   }

   public override bool Equals(Object obj) {

      //Check for null and compare run-time types.
      if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;

      Point p = (Point)obj;

      return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
   }
}
```

But if we know that the subclass directly inherits from `Object`, then **is the following equivalent**?  Note the `!base.Equals()` call:

```
class Point: Object {
   protected int x, y;

   public Point(int X, int Y) {
      this.x = X;
      this.y = Y;
   }

   public override bool Equals(Object obj) {

      if (!base.Equals(obj) || GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;

      Point p = (Point)obj;

      return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
   }
}
```

Comment: No, because `!base.Equals(obj)` will return `true`, causing your Equals method to return `false` if they're not the exact same object. If they are the same object, then the rest of your check is guaranteed to succeed. It will essentially make your override do nothing.

Comment: @Rob -- if `!base.Equals(obj)` returns true then you *want* to return false.

Comment: `base.Equals(obj)` will check if the current object and `obj` are the *exact* same object. That is, that they are pointers to the exact same object in memory. If they are different objects, your equals will immediately return false. If they *are* the same object, then `GetType() == obj.GetType()` and `(x == p.x) && (y == p.y)` are both guaranteed to return `true`

Comment: @roryap Not necessarily. They can be different objects but be *equal* (in this case if their x and y values are the same), which is the point in overriding the Equals method

Comment: Your `base.Equals(obj)` is not a good way to do a reference equality check.  It works fine if you are derived from `Object` but if you are derived from a class that does override `Equals` then you might not get the behavior you expect. Use `if(Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;` to get a quick reference equality check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case `this` reference is `null` you are right, that the check can be (but does not seem to be guaranteed) superfluous, as can be seen in `RuntimeHelpers.Equals` implementation quoted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26977636/2642204).

However, the `!base.Equals(obj)` check will break your `Equals`. When the references are not `null` - `!base.Equals` will also yield `true` for any different *references* not only for `null` values.

The scenario when it goes wrong is for example:

```
Point x = new Point(1,2);
Point y = new Point(1,2);

Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));  // will print 'False'
```

Even though `x` and `y` are equal in terms of your business logic, they are different objects so `base.Equal` returns `false`.

Comment: Oh!  Now I get it.  That's a pretty significant semantic error!

Comment: Is there ever a case where `this` is null in C# except when it's handwritten IL? I don't think it can be, but I may be wrong

Comment: @BartoszKP How, exactly? You cannot invoke a member method on a null object via `MethodInfo.Invoke`, and you most definitely cannot do `MyTest t = null; t.Equals(null)`.

Comment: @Rob Sorry, you're right. I confused things with extension methods and operator overloads. virtual methods (so, all "ordinary" class methods) always use the `this` pointer to access the virtual table so they will always crash when called on a null reference.