# Unable to get record from list by specific string value

Tags: c#, linq

I am having below class which contains some records :

```
public class File
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Coordinates> Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Now this Name contains string like below:

```
1st record :  "TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1,TestFile-Dump2.xlsx.sheet,TestFile-Dump1.xlsx.sheet1",
2nd record :  "TestFile-Dump2.xlsx.sheet1",
3rd record :  "TestFile-Dump2.xlsx.sheet3,TestFile-Dump1.xlsx.sheet5"
```

Suppose my current file name is  : **TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1**

```
var list = List<File>();
var File = list.FirstOrDefault(ls => ls.Name == "TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1"); //null
```

I want to find list of co-ordinates for above file name only but when i try to find i am getting null for file **TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1**.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem and how to do this with linq???

Comment: The problem is that the first record contains this file-name as a **substring** and not as a whole string

Comment: Use StartsWith. ls.Name.StartsWith("TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1")

Comment: Other users already suggested to use `Contains` or `StartsWith` to check for substrings, but be also aware, that you should compare strings with the `Equals`-method instead of the == operator, since the operation performs reference comparison (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3678810/3950370).

Comment: In this case ```==``` is completely fair and words as expected. The answer you linked to discusses the differences between ```==``` and ```Equals()```, but I don't see how they apply here. ```==``` doesn't compare references here. String uses operator overloading to map ```==``` directly to ```Equals()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first record contains the file-name, but as a substring. Since they are separated by commas you could use `String.Split` and `Enumerable.Contains`:

```
var File = list
    .FirstOrDefault(ls => ls.Name.Split(',').Contains("TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1"));
```

Comment: Yes this worked.Thank you so much for the help and please keep helping like this.Belated Happy new year :)

Answer (score 2):

Your example records don't contain a record with a `Name` of 'TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1'. The only ~matching~ one is the first, but that has a `Name` that only *contains* the string you are looking for.

In other words: Would it help to replace the `==` with a call to `Contains` to solve your problem? Or maybe you want to `Split()` the Name and compare the parts?

```
list.FirstOrDefault(ls => ls.Name.Contains("TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1"));
```

or

```
list.FirstOrDefault(ls => ls.Name.Split(',').Contains("TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The first record name doesn't equal to the whole string. so use startswith or contains.

```
list.FirstOrDefault(ls => ls.Name.Contains("TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1");

list.FirstOrDefault(ls => ls.Name.StartsWith("TestFile-Dump3.xlsx.sheet1");
```