# Does assign value to string creates new instance ? C#

Tags: c#

I know string is an alias of `System.String` but I am unable to understand this specific behavior.

```
string s = "ABC";
string s1 = "AB"+"C";
String s2 = new String("ABC");
```

`s == s1` returns `true` but `s == s2` returns `false`.

I know `string` is a reference type so the instance of `s` and `s1` refers two different instances but why is `s==s1` true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c

Comment: "AB"+"C" is turned into "ABC" by the compiler. And because strings are interned, s and s1 are references to the same string. The string type is special and is treated differently than other references types.

Comment: The more interesting question is why `s==s2 ` returns false.

Comment: The code you present does not compile with VS 2013. The line `String s2 = new String("ABC");`  results in `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.String(char*)' has some invalid arguments`  and `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char*'`

Comment: Why don't you present a complete little program and its original output? That would force you to fix your error and make it easier to examine the code. As it stands, it's a downvote for lacking research effort and sloppy presentation (which is inexcusable in programming).

Comment: `new String("ABC");` is only equal to a compiler error. Don't base questions on imaginary code.

Answer (score 3):

`why is s==s1 true ?`

This question has been answered before — `operator==()` has been overridden for strings in order to avoid the commonplace mistakes which would otherwise happen.

More interesting is the question why after `String s2 = new String("ABC");`, allegedly "s==s2 return false".

Well, the line as presented does not compile. What compiles is `String s2 = new String( new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C'});`, after which `s==s2`  is true.

Note that `string`  is simply a C# keyword, an alias for `System.String`; the two can be used interchangeably without changing the meaning of a program.