# if (sql_data_reader_value == "string") - Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I assigned a string from database data to c# variable. The string is being assigned properly. I tried using a message box and print the variable and it prints the value properly as a string. But when I compare that variable with another string it doesn't work. It always prints "This is Admin" although the two sides of the comparison is same.

```
SqlDataReader uid = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
while (uid.Read())
{
   string usertype = Convert.ToString(uid[0]);
   if (usertype =="User")
   {
      MessageBox.Show("This is User");
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("This is Admin");
   }
}
uid.Close();
```

Comment: what is value in `usertype` variable

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Set a breakpoint on the "if (usertype =="User")" line and inspect the value of usertype. You can use the VisualStudio watch window to compare those two values. Be aware the casing must be the same.

Comment: Are you sure `usertype` is `"User"` and not `"User "` or `"user"`?

Comment: Value in usertype is "User".@PrasadTelkikar

Comment: @Anny In the comments below, I thought you confirmed it wasn't that value (it differed by case)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried something like `string.Equals(string)` function ?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String      str1 = "abcd";
        String      str2 = "abcd";
        String      str3 = "ABCD";

        Console.WriteLine(str1.Equals(str2)); //True

        Console.WriteLine(str1.Equals(str3)); //False for upper case

        Console.WriteLine(str1.Equals(str3.ToLower())); //True Recommend this because you can compare the user with User and this isn't same.
    }
}
```

**Output:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pl72SQ

**Documentation:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_String_

Comment: *You cant compare 2 string with ==* Yes, you can. You should also add to your answer all relevant code instead of posting a link.

Comment: @Guy Sorry for that i fixed.

Comment: This option worked for me. Thank you. Didn't know that two srtings cannot be compared using == till now.

Comment: Yes, for example in C++ you can't compare 2 strings with == operator, i suppose this something similar on C#, don't remember put how Correct answer!

Comment: @Anny you can compare strings with `==` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same