# Unity: Comparing strings doesn't seem to work in this case?

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, if-statement, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare to strings in a function to be able to do stuff if it's true. However, for some reason the two strings I'm comparing are never equal to eachother.

I am creating a new string in a function, getting data from a Json and then comparing that string with another string in another class. This doesn't work for some reason. The Debug shows that both strings are equal, but the if-statement returns false.

I created two other string variables (hello & hello2) with the same value ("Hello") and this time it's comparing correctly.

Check the images below. What am I doing wrong?
As you can see in the console, both strings have the same value:

Image 1. Here's where I create the string (zoneId).

[image]

Image 2. Further down in the same function, same for-loop.
Here's where I'm trying to compare the string created in this function with another string from another class.
[image]

Image 3. As you can see in the console it's looping through the jsonArray. But it's returning false even though it's clear that both strings have the same value.
[image]

Image 4 and 5. Here I am testing with two other strings inside the function and they are working fine.
Does it has something to do calling a string from another class?

[image]
[image]

Here's how my other string in userInfo is set up:

```
public string userID { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Btw. Here's how my other string in userInfo is set up:

public string userID { get; private set; }

Does it has something to do  with get/set? I'm only getting the value so it shouldn't be any problem?

Comment: It appears `Main.Instance.userInfo.zoneID` has a space in front of the `2`, but `zoneId` does not. Please could you paste the Unity log output into your question instead of posting a screenshot (so I can verify this)?

Comment: **[Please don't post code as images!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)**

Comment: In general: If the value for this ID is an `int`, why using it as `string` at all? Rather serialize and deserialize it as `int` directly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use string.Equals for string comparison instead of operator == or !=.

[Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same)

Comment: Another thread about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals

Answer (score -1):

In Image 3, is there an additional space before the second 2?

How are you processing `Main.Instance.userInfo.zoneID`?

Comment: You may be right. There seems to be a space somewhere but I can't figure out how and where. The zoneID from userInfo is coming from www.downloadHandler.text, from a php script. The script is returning the zoneID with echo $row["zoneID"];